# Update or create from file CSV in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework

In my view, I created this which allows to add several plants thanks to a CSV file :

```
class UploadFileView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = serializer.validated_data['file']
        reader = pd.read_csv(file)
        for _, row in reader.iterrows():
            new_file = Plant(
                name=row['Name'],
                plant_description=row["Plant description"],
                family=Family.objects.get(name=row['Family']),
                category=PlantCategory.objects.get(name=row['Category']),
                facility_rate=row["Facility rate"],
                seedling_depth=row['Seedling depth'],
                seedling_distance=row["Seedling distance"],
                row_spacing=row['Row spacing'],
                sunshine_index=row["Sunshine index"],
                irrigation_index=row["Irrigation index"],
                soil_nature=row['Soil nature'],
                soil_type=row["Soil type"],
                fertilizer_type=row['Fertilizer type'],
                acidity_index=row["Acidity index"],
                days_before_sprouting=row["Days before sprouting"],
                average_harvest_time=row['Average harvest time'],
                soil_depth=row["Soil depth"],
                plant_height=row['Plant height'],
                suitable_for_indoor_growing=row["Suitable for indoor growing"],
                suitable_for_outdoor_growing=row["Suitable for outdoor growing"],
                suitable_for_pot_culture=row['Suitable for pot culture'],
                hardiness_index=row["Hardiness index"],
                no_of_plants_per_meter=row['No of plants per meter'],
                no_of_plants_per_square_meter=row["No of plants per square meter"],
                min_temperature=row["Min temperature"],
                max_temperature=row['Max temperature'],
                time_to_transplant=row["Time to transplant"],
            )
            new_file.save()
        return Response({"status": "Success : plant(s) created"},
                        status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The problem being that if the plants are already created there is an error message but I would like to make sure to identify if the plant is not created then we have created it, otherwise we update it with the new ones CSV file data.

I saw that there was an [update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method on Django but I couldn't manage to implement it with my code.

If anyone can help me that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

here you are

```
class UploadFileView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = serializer.validated_data['file']
        reader = pd.read_csv(file)
        for _, row in reader.iterrows():
            Plant.objects.update_or_create(
                name=row['Name'],
                plant_description=row["Plant description"],
                family=Family.objects.get(name=row['Family']),
                category=PlantCategory.objects.get(name=row['Category']),
                facility_rate=row["Facility rate"],
                seedling_depth=row['Seedling depth'],
                seedling_distance=row["Seedling distance"],
                row_spacing=row['Row spacing'],
                sunshine_index=row["Sunshine index"],
                irrigation_index=row["Irrigation index"],
                soil_nature=row['Soil nature'],
                soil_type=row["Soil type"],
                fertilizer_type=row['Fertilizer type'],
                acidity_index=row["Acidity index"],
                days_before_sprouting=row["Days before sprouting"],
                average_harvest_time=row['Average harvest time'],
                soil_depth=row["Soil depth"],
                plant_height=row['Plant height'],
                suitable_for_indoor_growing=row["Suitable for indoor growing"],
                suitable_for_outdoor_growing=row["Suitable for outdoor growing"],
                suitable_for_pot_culture=row['Suitable for pot culture'],
                hardiness_index=row["Hardiness index"],
                no_of_plants_per_meter=row['No of plants per meter'],
                no_of_plants_per_square_meter=row["No of plants per square meter"],
                min_temperature=row["Min temperature"],
                max_temperature=row['Max temperature'],
                time_to_transplant=row["Time to transplant"],
            )
        return Response({"status": "Success : plant(s) created"},
                        status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: yes it's my code

Comment: your code is updated in here check it.

Comment: this should work. Did you try?

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen sorry thank you very much I'll try and I'll come back to you!

Comment: You are welcome nice to see that!

Comment: I just tested by just changing the description of a plant in my CSV file but when I import it to add it to my database it gives me an error message `KeyError: 'Name'` I think that it is because in my database there are already plants with the same names as those present in my CSV file but suddenly the `update_or_create()` method does not work?

Comment: I usually use `get_or_create`. Try it. It gets the object or creates a new one if not exist

Comment: Thanks, I did this: `obj, created = Plant.objects.get_or_create(... )`
But what do I have to do with the `obj` and `created` variables because there, testing it always gives me the error: `KeyError: 'Name'`